# Displaying Entities in TreeView using MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, mvvm

I am making a WPF application following MVVM pattern. In this i am using entity framework,

my entity structure is simple, it has 3 entities: department, course, books,

a department can have many courses, and a course can have many books,

now i want to show this in a treeview, so my output in wpf should look like this,

```
Department1

  Course1

    Book1

    Book2

  Course2

    Book3

Department2

  Course

     Book

Department3
```

in my ViewModel i have EntityContext object. But i dont know how to show this in a treeview.
how i can do this.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I prepared the small sample to replicate this..

```
<Window x:Class="TestApp.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:this="clr-namespace:TestApp"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

    <Window.DataContext>
        <this:TreeViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>

    <Window.Resources>

        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Courses}" DataType="{x:Type this:Department}">
            <Label Content="{Binding DepartmentName}"/>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Books}" DataType="{x:Type this:Course}">
            <Label Content="{Binding CourseName}"/>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type this:Book}">
            <Label Content="{Binding BookName}"/>
        </DataTemplate>

    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Departments}">

        </TreeView>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Model and ViewModel classes.

```
public class Book :ViewModelBase
    {
        private string bookname = string.Empty;

        public string BookName
        {
            get
            {
                return bookname;
            }
            set
            {
                bookname = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("BookName");
            }
        }

        public Book(string bookname)
        {
            BookName = bookname;
        }
    }
```

Department class

```
public class Department : ViewModelBase
    {
        private List<Course> courses;

        public Department(string depname)
        {
            DepartmentName = depname;
            Courses = new List<Course>()
            {
                new Course("Course1"),
                new Course("Course2")
            };
        }

        public List<Course> Courses
        {
            get
            {
                return courses;
            }
            set
            {
                courses = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Courses");
            }
        }

        public string DepartmentName
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }
```

Course class

```
public class Course :ViewModelBase
    {
        private List<Book> books;

        public Course(string coursename)
        {
            CourseName = coursename;
            Books = new List<Book>()
            {
                new Book("JJJJ"),
                new Book("KKKK"),
                new Book("OOOOO")
            };
        }

        public List<Book> Books
        {
            get
            {
                return books;
            }
            set
            {
                books = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Books");
            }
        }

        public string CourseName
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }
```

TreeViewModel class.

```
public class TreeViewModel :ViewModelBase
    {
        private List<Department> departments;

        public TreeViewModel()
        {
            Departments = new List<Department>()
            {
                new Department("Department1"),
                new Department("Department2")
            };
        }

        public List<Department> Departments
        {
            get
            {
                return departments;
            }
            set
            {
                departments = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Departments");
            }
        }
    }
```

ViewModelBase class.

```
public class ViewModelBase :INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public void OnPropertyChanged(string propname)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propname));
            }
        }
    }
```

Finally it displays the data in the hierarchical format.. I hope this would satisfy you...

Comment: now i want to add selected item, how i can do that, like selected item in tree can be department book or course, there is SelectedItem in list view, but in hierarchicalDataTemplate there is no selected item,

Answer (score 3):

You have to define hierarchy data template template for this [Here](http://complexdatatemplates.codeplex.com/) is the sample how to use this.

Answer (score 2):

Based on 'David Bekham' answer i created an more generic way to display the items

hops it helps:

define a generic HierarchicalDataTemplate

```
   <HierarchicalDataTemplate 
      ItemsSource="{Binding ChildItems}" 
      DataType="{x:Type viewModels:TVItemViewModel}">
                   <Label Content="{Binding Name}" />
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

here the viewmodel (if your content is non static you need to implement the viewModelbase class )

```
public class TVItemViewModel 
    {
        private bool isSelected;
        private string name;

        public TVItemViewModel(string name)
        {
            this.Name = name;
        }
        public string Name
        {
            get => name;
            set => name= value;
        }

        public bool IsSelected
        {
            get => isSelected;
            set =>  isSelected= value;
        }

        public ObservableCollection<TVItemViewModel> ChildItems { get; set; }
    }
```

and in the MainViewModel i create a root collection like

```
 TvItems = new ObservableCollection<TVItemViewModel>() 
            { new TVItemViewModel("RootItem1") 
                { ChildItems = new ObservableCollection<TVItemViewModel>() 
                    { new TVItemViewModel("Child1"), 
                       new TVItemViewModel("Child2"), 
                        new TVItemViewModel("Child3)
                    }
                }
            };
```

I hope someone finds this usefull

Answer (score 0):

We need to define the 'n' level of HierachialDataTemplate for the nested level we want.. We will have ItemsSource property for the HierarchicalDataTemplate class to define this.. We can do the same for the MenuControl also..