# "Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.Parameter name: index" when adding new item to ObservableCollection<T>

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, viewmodel, observablecollection

I get a such exception:

> 'FooStorageStorage.Add(new TreeViewItem() { Header=i.ToString()})'
>   threw an exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException':
>   "Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.\r\nParameter
>   name: index"

I have a property in viewModel:

```
private ObservableCollection<TreeViewItem> fooStorage=new ObservableCollection<TreeViewItem>();
public ObservableCollection<TreeViewItem> FooStorage
{
   get { return facetStorage; }
   set { facetStorage = value; }
}
```

However, after I cleared `FooStorage` and trying to add new item:

```
private void LoadData()
{
    if (FooStorage.Count > 0)
    {
       FooStorage.Clear();
    }
    for (int k = 0; k < lengthOfColl; k++)            
    {
       FooStorage.Add(new TreeViewItem() { Header=k.ToString()});//here is exception
    }
}
```

I've got an above exception.

When I call a method LoadData() at the first time, it all works okay. Then if I call a method LoadData() at the second time, then I get a such exception.

Have anybody met a such exception? The most interesting thing that I cannot reproduce this exception in a test project.

StackTrace:

> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException was unhandled   HResult=-2146233086
>   Message=Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
>   Parameter name: index   ParamName=index   Source=PresentationCore
>   StackTrace:
>          at System.Windows.Media.VisualCollection.Insert(Int32 index, Visual visual)
>          at System.Windows.Controls.UIElementCollection.InsertInternal(Int32
>   index, UIElement element)
>          at System.Windows.Controls.Panel.AddChildren(GeneratorPosition pos, Int32 itemCount)
>          at System.Windows.Controls.Panel.OnItemsChangedInternal(Object sender, ItemsChangedEventArgs args)
>          at System.Windows.Controls.Panel.OnItemsChanged(Object sender, ItemsChangedEventArgs args)
>          at System.Windows.Controls.ItemContainerGenerator.OnItemAdded(Object
>   item, Int32 index)
>          at System.Windows.Controls.ItemContainerGenerator.OnCollectionChanged(Object
>   sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs args)
>          at System.Windows.WeakEventManager.ListenerList`1.DeliverEvent(Object
>   sender, EventArgs e, Type managerType)
>          at System.Windows.WeakEventManager.DeliverEvent(Object sender, EventArgs args)
>          at System.Collections.Specialized.CollectionChangedEventManager.OnCollectionChanged(Object
>   sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs args)
>          at System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler.Invoke(Object
>   sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
>          at System.Windows.Data.CollectionView.OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs
>   args)
>          at System.Windows.Controls.ItemCollection.OnViewCollectionChanged(Object
>   sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
>          at System.Windows.WeakEventManager.ListenerList`1.DeliverEvent(Object
>   sender, EventArgs e, Type managerType)
>          at System.Windows.WeakEventManager.DeliverEvent(Object sender, EventArgs args)
>          at System.Collections.Specialized.CollectionChangedEventManager.OnCollectionChanged(Object
>   sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs args)
>          at System.Windows.Data.CollectionView.OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs
>   args)
>          at System.Windows.Data.ListCollectionView.ProcessCollectionChangedWithAdjustedIndex(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs
>   args, Int32 adjustedOldIndex, Int32 adjustedNewIndex)
>          at System.Windows.Data.ListCollectionView.ProcessCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs
>   args)
>          at System.Windows.Data.CollectionView.OnCollectionChanged(Object sender,
>   NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs args)
>          at System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1.OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs
>   e)
>          at System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1.InsertItem(Int32
>   index, T item)
>          at System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection`1.Add(T item)
>          at ModuleA.ViewModel.PersonControlViewModel.LoadData(IPerson person) in D:\WPF\...\ViewModel\PersonControlViewModel.cs:line 110
>          at Prism.Commands.DelegateCommand`1.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<.ctor>b__0(Object
>   o)
>          at Prism.Commands.DelegateCommandBase.<>c__DisplayClass5_0.<.ctor>b__0(Object
>   arg)
>          at Prism.Commands.DelegateCommandBase.d__14.MoveNext()
>       --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>          at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)
>          at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)
>          at Prism.Commands.DelegateCommandBase.d__12.MoveNext()
>       --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>          at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.<>c.b__6_0(Object
>   state)
>          at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate
>   callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
>          at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source,
>   Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
>          at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
>          at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext(Object
>   state)
>          at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)
>          at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)
>          at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
>          at MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext.Run(CulturePreservingExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
>          at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
>          at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
>          at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
>          at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
>          at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
>          at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate
>   callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
>          at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source,
>   Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
>          at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority
>   priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32
>   numArgs)
>          at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
>          at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg)
>          at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame
>   frame)
>          at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(DispatcherFrame frame)
>          at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(Object ignore)
>          at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(Window window)
>          at System.Windows.Application.Run(Window window)
>          at System.Windows.Application.Run()
>          at PrototypeBootstrapper.App.Main() in D:\WPF...\Src\PrototypeBootstrapper\obj\Debug\App.g.cs:line 0
>          at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
>          at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
>          at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
>          at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
>          at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)
>          at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)
>          at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
>          at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()   InnerException:

**Update:**

I am adding new `TreeViewItem's` from `FooStorage` to different `TreeView` placed inside of HeaderTemplate of `DataGridTextBoxColumn`. So when user clicks at `Header1` of `DataGridTextBoxColumn2`, then `TreeView` of `Header1` is populated by `FooStorage` from viewModel. OK. The when user clicks at `Header2` of `DataGridTextBoxColumn2`, then `TreeView` of `Header2` should be populated by `FooStorage` from viewModel, however when I `Clear()` and `Add()` new items to `FooStorage`, then I've got an above exception.

Comment: Post the call stack here as well.

Comment: Any event triggered on adding?

Comment: Please mention all subscribers to any event of the `ObservableCollection`. Obviously some other code is doing something wrong either on `Clear()` or `Add()`. Read [ask], provide [mcve].

Comment: @CodeCaster No, it is just one place where I `Add()` and `Clear` values.

Comment: @PatrickHofman there is no event triggered on adding. I just every time `Clear()` and `Delete()` a collection, when the method `LoadData` is called

Comment: @downvoter why do you downvote? What other details do you need?

Comment: It does change the UI. Something wrong in the bindings?

Comment: You are using `FooStorage` in a binding, the exception is thrown by one of the listeners. Where and how do you call `LoadData()` ? I suspect something illegal in `ObservableCollection<>` usage. Or perhaps in the binding itself.

Comment: @PatrickHofman yeah, you are right. It changes UI. I do not know whether something wrong in the bindings, however when I call a method `LoadData()`, it all works okay. Then if  I call a method `LoadData()` at the second time, then I get a such exception.

Comment: Try to see if it helps to disable that section in the UI.

Comment: @PatrickHofman yeah. It helper. However, I cannot see new `TreeViewItems` in my `TreeView`. How can I solve this exception without disabling section in the UI?

Comment: You should not use [`TreeViewItem`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.treeviewitem(v=vs.110).aspx) directly in ViewModel. Moreover framework elements (including `TreeViewItem`) can have only one parent at a time. Maybe adding new `TreeViewItem` which is then used in different places is your problem (cba to check sources if it's the case, simply don't do it). Rather use `TreeViewItemViewModel` (call it shorter, e.g. `ItemViewModel`).

Comment: @Sinatr could you show some example where I can add `Items` on demand(when I click at the ancestor and nested nodes should be loaded)

Comment: @Sinatr what does CBA mean? please write your answer and I'll mark it.

Comment: There are plenty of [examples](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10908477/1997232) of how to bind TreeView (using `HierachialDataTemplate`). You simply have to load data in the getter of one of properties. I don't think this question needs answer, better you ask another question regarding your initial problem (and not attempted solution with `ListViewItem` in ViewModel) in case you can't do it alone for whatever reasons. That would be much more useful to others. P.S.: [cba](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=cba) is a bad term.

Comment: @Sinatr it will prevent from new errors by new users

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just would like to say that passing UI Element `TreeViewItem` to `ViewModel` is a bad practice. So maybe adding new `TreeViewItem` which is then used in different places was my problem.

As @Sinatr said:

> You should not use TreeViewItem directly in ViewModel. Moreover
>   framework elements (including TreeViewItem) can have only one parent
>   at a time. Maybe adding new TreeViewItem which is then used in
>   different places is your problem (cba to check sources if it's the
>   case, simply don't do it). Rather use TreeViewItemViewModel (call it
>   shorter, e.g. ItemViewModel).

Patrick Hofman gave me advice to disable that section in the UI and after I disabled it, then there was no problems.

So I've concluded that I've met consequences of using bad practice and was punished. **Avoid bad practices. And `ObservableCollection<T>` is not guilty! Sorry, `ObservableCollection<T>`.**

[Now I am learning about TreeView by Josh Smith](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26288/Simplifying-the-WPF-TreeView-by-Using-the-ViewMode).