# Wpf TreeView that has columns, with UI Virtualization and DataVirtualization

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview, wpf-controls, data-virtualization

I'm looking for a wpf control (free or commercial).
The tree should support all the regular tree view Characteristics (styles, data templates, control template, ...) and support being laid out with Columns (sort of like the Watch window in Visual Studio).

But also:

1. Good virtualization - should support thousands of elements
2. Built-in **Data Virtualization** - The loading and processing of the data is slow and could not be done all at once and on a certain order (kind of like paging)
3. View Model support and Binding, I prefer to investigate the tree using kind of a view model instead of investigate the tree itself
4. Built-in support for search and filtering on the data representation and then reflect the matches on the visual elements on the tree
5. **Accurate, fast scrolling** and option to move to a specific element (I prefer, using the ViewModel representation of the item).

I **don't want** to build the tree myself, I'm looking for existing implementation with at least support for virtualization and data virtualization.

Answer (score 3):

The best control I know who can apply your requirements is [Telerik RadTreeView](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/wpf/controls/radtreeview/overview2.html). Check out the [demo](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/wpf/controls/radtreeview/how-to/implement-search-filter-sort.html#implement-search-filter-and-sort). Pros:

The RadTreeView API supports UI Virtualization, which processes only information loaded in the viewable area, which reduces the memory footprint of the application and speeds up loading time thus enhancing additionally the UI performance

The performance of the Telerik RadTreeView control when operating with huge amount of items is significantly optimized through its load on demand feature. This mechanism lets the nodes load their child nodes as the user expands the parent by clicking on the “+” icon

The RadTreeView is a data-driven control, designed to display large amounts of hierarchical data and it does not provide searching, filtering and sorting functionality out of the box. Hence, such 
operations should be implemented on the data it represents. [Example](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/wpf/controls/radtreeview/how-to/implement-search-filter-sort.html#implement-search-filter-and-sort)

Comment: thanks for your answer hope to find a control with a built in support for data virtualization. (I want to have some kind of paging behavior) somthing like: "http://www.devzest.com/blog/post/WPF-Data-Virtualization.aspx" but, as a tree

Answer (score 2):

The best example I've ever seen is [TreeView by Josh Smith](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26288/Simplifying-the-WPF-TreeView-by-Using-the-ViewMode). It uses Load-On-Demand loading and has Text Search.

To include `DataVirtualization` you should use:

```
<TreeView
    VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing = "True"
    VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode = "Recycling" />
```

But be careful, `Virtualization` **only works when the `TreeView` is using `Binding`**, and **not when the nodes are generated one by one in the code like in the following example:**

```
TreeViewItem rootItem = new TreeViewItem() { Header = "Item Level 0" };

for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
    TreeViewItem itemLevel1 = new TreeViewItem() { Header = "Item Level 1" };
    itemLevel1.Items.Add(new TreeViewItem());
    rootItem.Items.Add(itemLevel1);
}
```

**Update:**

You can use [the DevExpress TreeList](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WPF/Tree_List/) control. It is free-trial.

Or [Telerik's TreeView](http://www.telerik.com/products/wpf/treeview.aspx) control. It is 30 day free-trial. 
See their demos and you can even download and try them.

**Update1:**

If you have any doubts about performance [TreeView by Josh Smith](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26288/Simplifying-the-WPF-TreeView-by-Using-the-ViewMode), then I can say about my experince:

- I have 500 nodes and time to load these items is 0.0003982 seconds
- I can scroll up and scroll down and there is no any freezing UI (**perfect Data Virtualization**)
- Nested nodes are perfectly opened as Josh Smith uses **Lazy Loading**
- All nodes can have templates. So you can set any image or design you want
- This `TreeView` does not absolutely violate MVVM rules, cause it uses `viewModels` for `TreeViewItems`. It means you will not meet strange errors or exceptions if you would have `TreeViewITem` in your `viewModel`. For example, [this error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36009413/specified-argument-was-out-of-the-range-of-valid-values-parameter-name-index).

To conclude, I would like to say I am really glad that I've chosen `TreeView by JoshSmith` in my production application cause it is really simple to support and edit it. It has really great performance.

Photo of my `TreeView`:

[image]

Comment: @EliDagan you are right. Please, read carefully my answer. I've written: **not when the nodes are generated one by one in the code like in the following example**

Comment: thanks, But I need a virtualization on all the tree not just for each level of element (like the TreeView implementation).
And I need also a Data Virtualization (if possible, a built-in support) because I need to load a different chunks of the tree each time

Comment: @EliDagan These VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing = "True" VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode ="Recycling" rows are for DataVirtualization for the whole tree, so *each level of element*  is included:). In addition, the TreeView by Josh Smith has TextSearch. It is all what you want.

Comment: as I said before. The TreeView from the framework is not an optional because it has very bad performance when using it with a big set of hierarchical data that each one of its nodes has a lot of child. (deep and wide tree)
Also I need Data virtualization that will enable me to load different parts of the data and keep tracking of the data it has and the data that missing.
I know that I can build it myself but I want already existing solution.

Comment: Hi, I'm looking for someone who already try free or commercial implementation and can share